# Merge multiple dataframes in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I need to merge 20 dataframes having thousand to million records each.

Each dataframe has 2 columns:

df1 :

```
root
  |-- id: string (nullable = true)
  |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
```

df2 :

```
root
  |-- id: string (nullable = true)
  |-- col2: string (nullable = true)
```

Final df:

```
root
  |-- id: string (nullable = true)
  |-- col1: string (nullable = true) 
  |-- col1: string (nullable = true) 
  .
  .
  |-- col19: string (nullable = true)
```

I tried

```
df = df1 
        .join(df2, 'ID', 'full') \
        .join(df3, 'ID', 'full') \
        .join(df4, 'ID', 'full') \
        .join(df5, 'ID', 'full') 
        .
        .
        .
        .join(df19, 'ID', 'full')
```

It's failing after 30-40 mins with **No memory left error**. Tried with 4-16 executors with 8 GB memory.

There are duplicate ids in the dataframe. So its making joins worse.

---

- Is there another way to perform merge on these dataframes?
- Will sorting and dropping duplicate prior to join help?
- Will join order also matter like keeping high records df first?
- Will splitting 20 joins into multiple joins (e.g. batch of 5) and performing an action on them (e.g. count) and then join these batches help?

Comment: Dropping duplicates should definitely help, as otherwise you may experience exponential growth of data: if 10 dataframes have 2 rows with same id, after they are joined, you'll have pow(2,10) = 1024 rows with this id in a result.

Comment: your goal is to `join` these dataframes or do `union` over them?

Comment: @moriarty007 all dataframes have 1 different column. So final df should have **1 + no. of dataframes** columns. I believe this merging is done via join only.

Comment: Try breaking the join into multiple statements. `df1to5 = df1 
        .join(df2, 'ID', 'full') \
        .join(df3, 'ID', 'full') \
        .join(df4, 'ID', 'full') \
        .join(df5, 'ID', 'full')`
`df6to10; df11to15; df16to20` and then join `df1to5.join(df6to10, "ID", "full")`. and others. See if that works.

Answer (score 0):

what about if you normalize the df column names, something like this

```
df1

root
  |-- id: string (nullable = true)
  |-- **col1**: string (nullable = true)  

df2

root
  |-- id: string (nullable = true)
  |-- **col1**: string (nullable = true)
```

and after that you can union

```
df1.union(df2).dropDuplicates(subset="id")
```

Comment: Union adds data row-wise. I want to merge all the columns from all dataframes. Apparently join is the only option I have.